# Filtering pandas dataframe on multiple conditions using loc returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, filter, pandas-loc

I am trying to filter my dataframe on multiple conditions using loc

The data is coming from an Excel file that I imported into the dataframe using df = pd.read_csv()

Here is sample structure from the df using df.head() :

[df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIy18.png)

and I need to filter on the following criteria: State-Gov, Bachelors, Never-Married, Adm-Clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, United States, <=50k

Here is the code that I wrote. It returns the correct columns, but no rows the df is empty :

```
df.loc[(df['Sector']=='State-Gov') & (df['Education']=='Bachelors') & (df['Married']=='Never-Married') & 
   (df['Job']=='Adm-Clerical') & (df['Family']=='Not-in-Family') & (df['Race']=='White') & (df['Gender']=='Male') & 
   (df['Location']=='United-States') & (df['Income']=='<=50k'), ['Sector', 'Education', 'Married', 'Job', 'Family', 'Race', 'Gender', 'Location', 'Income']]
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: For example `United States` shouldn't be `United-States`? With `-`? Same with `State=Gov` etc.

Comment: Good catch thanks! I fixed this but am still getting an empty dataframe

Comment: When I do df.loc(df['Sector']=='State-gov') I get TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: ah yes duh, this fixed the type error but still returned an empty df. Btw thank you Andrej for your help and patience!

Comment: What does `print(f'[{df.iloc[0]["Sector"]}]')` print?

Comment: Output is [ State-gov] , maybe that leading space is the problem? Edit: df.loc[df['Sector']==' State-Gov'] still returns empty df

Comment: Yes, there's a leading space... so this is the problem. First you should clean your data (strip whitespaces etc.)

Comment: `print(df.loc[df["Sector"].str.strip() == "State-gov"])` should print some rows.

Comment: Finally solved it, thank you so much Andrej you rock!!

Comment: I'll write an answer so you can accept and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in "not-cleaned" data (whitespaces before and after string values).

Solution is to clean the data (using `.str.strip()` etc.), for example:

```py
print(df.loc[df["Sector"].str.strip() == "State-gov"])
```